# How to quote replacement in preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

E.g. in the code below, if the user wants the new content of the template to be the string `C:\Users\Admin\1`, the `\1` part will become `BEGIN this was the original content of the template END`, which is something I don't want.

```
preg_replace('/(BEGIN.*?END)/su', $_POST['content'], $template);
```

Comment: Perhaps, `preg_replace('/(BEGIN.*?END)/su', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $_POST['content']), $template);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short,** use this function to quote a dynamic replacement pattern:

```
function preg_quote_replacement($repl_str) {
    return str_replace(array('\\', '$'), array('\\\\', '\\$'), $repl_str);
}
```

The thing is, you need to escape the backslash in the replacement pattern. See [`preg_replace` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> To use backslash in replacement, it must be doubled (`"\\\\"` PHP string).

It can be done with a mere `str_replace` function:

```
$repl = 'C:\Users\Admin\1';
$template = "BEGIN this was the original content of the template END";
echo preg_replace('/(BEGIN.*?END)/su', str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $repl), $template);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/l22gJ9)

However, **NOTE** that the `$` symbol is *also* special in the replacement pattern. Thus, we also need to escape this symbol. The order of these prelimnary replacements matter: first, we need to escape the `\`, and then the `$`:

```
$r = '$1\1';
echo preg_replace('~(B.*?S)~', str_replace(array('\\', '$'), array('\\\\', '\\$'), $r), "BOSS");
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/mINuHj) (in your code, `preg_replace('/(BEGIN.*?END)/su', str_replace(array('\\', '$'), array('\\\\', '\\$'), $_POST['content']), $template);` or use the function I added at the start of the post).

Comment: Seems to be perfect in this case, but what if `$_POST['content']` is different? Is \ the only thing that needs to be escaped?

Comment: I have updated the answer and think that is all you need to do with a dynamic replacement. Only ``\`` and `$` are special in the PCRE replacement pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [T-Regx](http://t-regx.com) which [automatically quotes all kinds of references with replacing](https://t-regx.com/docs/replace-with):

```
pattern('(\d+)cm')->replace('I have 15cm and 192cm')->all()->with('<\\2>');
```

results in

```
I have <\2> and <\2>
```

Also works with `$1` and `${2}` references.

PS: T-Regx has also tools for quoting user data in *patterns*, using [pattern building](https://t-regx.com/docs/pattern-building)!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same function and instead I learned, that you should not quote the replacement. You should use `preg_replace_callback` instead. https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/9663